# How can i run these queries so they will stop once a result is found

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to pull data off one table using the following queries but I need it to run the first query and stop if it gets a result and then run the second query if it doesn't. Every time I run the search I get two results but one of the two results is echoing that there is no result. I plan on adding more queries as well so that the results can be returned as needed. I have been working on this problem for a few days already and I finally thought I would ask for help. Thanks in advance.

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname");                                                                               
if(!$conn) {                                                                                                                                              
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                         

//echo $conn->host_info . "\n";                                                                                                                           

$sql = "SELECT * FROM SCANMSTR WHERE BadgeNumber LIKE $query AND Active = 1 AND ExpirationDate >= curdate()";                                             
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);                                                                                                                      

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {                                                                                                                       
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {                                                                                                            
        echo "Badge Number: " .$row["BadgeNumber"]. "- Name: " . $row["BadgeName"]. "<br>";                                                               
     }                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                         

else  {                                                                                                                                                   
  echo "Not in system1";                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                         


$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM SCANMSTR WHERE BadgeNumber LIKE $query and Active = 0 AND Barred = 1 AND Lost = 1";                                                
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);                                                                                                                    

if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) >0) {                                                                                                                       
   while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {                                                                                                          
        echo "Card not active";  }                                                                                                                        
      }                                                                                                                                                   

else {                                                                                                                                                    
   echo "Not in system";
```

//Newly added code

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) {
  if ($row['Active']) {
        echo "Badge Number: " .$row["BadgeNumber"]. "- Name: ".$row["BadgeName"]. "
";
     }
else {
        echo "Card is inactive";
}
if ($row) {
    if($row['Barred'])
        echo "Cardholder is barred";
}
if ($row) {
    if($row['Lost'])
        echo "Card reported Lost";
}
      }
else  {
    echo "Not in system";

Comment: Move your second one into the `ELSE` of your first one? Set a variable in your `else` and check that variable before running your second statement? Only submit one SQL statement as a UNION of your two sql statements?

Comment: I have tried and it gives me an empty page. it doesn't like it.i haven't tried a union yet though I didn't know you could UNION with the same table. I will see if it works. thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. The only constraint is that the number of columns and the column types match between the two result sets. The bonus with the UNION is that it's only one trip to the database.

Comment: @JNevill I add a union and no luck. I removed tags $sql and $sql1 added UNION [ALL] in between both queries.

Comment: @JNevill thank you the UNION worked and thanks toTorbjorn Stabo for showing me the correct syntax and placement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps put both queries in one, and only fetch the first row found? Something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT BadgeNumber, BadgeName, Active FROM SCANMSTR WHERE BadgeNumber LIKE $query AND Active = 1 AND ExpirationDate >= CURDATE()
        UNION
        SELECT BadgeNumber, BadgeName, Active FROM SCANMSTR WHERE BadgeNumber LIKE $query and Active = 0 AND Barred = 1 AND Lost = 1
        LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) {
    if ($row['Active']) {
        echo "Badge Number: " .$row["BadgeNumber"]. "- Name: " . $row["BadgeName"]. "<br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Card not active";  
    }
}
else {
    echo "Not in system";
}
```

**Edit** To extend this to N checks you can either add more

```
UNION
SELECT ...
```

lines to $sql, like

```
$sql = "SELECT BadgeNumber, BadgeName, Active FROM SCANMSTR WHERE BadgeNumber LIKE $query AND Active = 1 AND ExpirationDate >= CURDATE()
        UNION
        SELECT BadgeNumber, BadgeName, Active FROM SCANMSTR WHERE BadgeNumber LIKE $query and Active = 0 AND Barred = 1 AND Lost = 1
        UNION
        SELECT ...
        UNION
        SELECT ...
        ...
        LIMIT 1";
```

Because of the LIMIT 1 the query will check as many of the SELECT queries as needed to get one row to return. So even if multiple SELECT matches the person(not sure if it is/should be possible?) you'll get the first of them, not all.

*Or* you could simply fetch the columns needed for *all* the checks, and then do them in your backend logic:

```
$sql = "SELECT BadgeNumber, BadgeName, Active, ExpirationDate 
        FROM SCANMSTR 
        WHERE BadgeNumber LIKE $query
        LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) {
    if ($row['Active']) {
        echo "Badge Number: " .$row["BadgeNumber"]. "- Name: " . $row["BadgeName"]. "<br>";
    }
    else if ($row['ExpirationDate'] < date('Y-m-d')) {
        echo "Card not active";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Not in system";
}
```

Personally I think I'd do it this way, it feels more clean, less repeated SQL, etc. Both ways should work, though :)..

Comment: That did it I was trying to get the syntax correct and your response showed me what I was doing wrong. Do you think that this can be further modified to add two more queries? Thanks again.

Comment: @ventron Good to hear :)! I'm not 100% sure I understand you correctly, but yes, if you're looking for more conditions like "Card not active" I guess it should work. As long as you're aware of the "priority chain" of course. (The $sql query will only fetch data for the **first** condition matched, right?)

Comment: I played with it and after I added the other SELECT statements I add some if statements under the initial if you gave me and I can pull what I needed. it is more repeated but it pulls if the card is active but lost or if its not active because of the lost status. I will try to edit my code so you can see. Thanks again you have really help a lot. this was kicking my butt for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

You put in your second statement into the first ELSE of your first statement like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname");
if(!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//echo $conn->host_info . "\n";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM SCANMSTR WHERE BadgeNumber LIKE $query AND Active = 1 AND ExpirationDate >= curdate()";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Badge Number: " .$row["BadgeNumber"]. "- Name: " . $row["BadgeName"]. "<br>";
     }
}

else  {                                                                                                                                                   
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM SCANMSTR WHERE BadgeNumber LIKE $query and Active = 0 AND Barred = 1 AND Lost = 1";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) >0) {
   while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        echo "Card not active";  }
      }

else {
   echo "Not in system";}

 }
```

Comment: I gave it a shot and I get no results at all. Thanks